# Не работает свойство height/width

Tags: css, less, width, height

Есть элемент, типа всплывающего окна `.login__window`. Нужно сделать так, чтобы его видно не было, но он появлялся при наведении на кнопку. Делать через `display: none/ visibility: hidden` не хочу, так как с ним не работает transition. Делаю через `max-height`.

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .login__open {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    top: 1em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 5em;
  }
  .login__open:hover ~ .login__window {
    max-height: 10em;
  }
  .login__window {
    display: table;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ebf1ff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 1vh 0 1vh 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    z-index: 100;
    
    min-width: 25vw;
    max-height: 0; //не работает
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2vh;
    right: 1em;
    top: 3em;
  }
  .row { 
    display: table-row; 
    margin: 1em;
  }
  .row > * { display: table-cell; }
```

```html
 <div id="login">
  <button class="login__open">Entrer</button>

  <article class="login__window popup">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="">Votre login:</label>
      <input type="text" name="login-login" id="login-login" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Login" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label for="">Votre mot de passe:</label>
      <input type="password" name="login-password" id="login-password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="password" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button>Entrer</button>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Так вот элементу `.login__window` совершенно не важно, стоит ли `width`, стоит ли `height`, стоит ли `max-width/height`, ни на одно из этих свойств он не реагирует.
P.S. написано на `LESS`, в `CSS` конвертируется правильно, там есть свойство height: 0, и инструменты разработчика в хроме тоже его показывают. Свойства наверху в комментариях заданы в других частях кода, а `min-width` и `min-height` закомментировал, чтобы проверить, будет ли без них работать. Не помогает.

Comment: а где сама вёрстка ? html какой ?

Answer (score 1):

Не много с эмитировал высоту которая вам не далась

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.login__open {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 5em;
}

.login__open:hover~.login__window {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.login__window {
  display: table;
  background-color: #ebf1ff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 1vh 0 1vh 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all .5s linear;
  min-width: 25vw;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2vh;
  right: 1em;
  top: 3em;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.row>* {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <button class="login__open">Entrer</button>

  <article class="login__window popup">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="">Votre login:</label>
      <input type="text" name="login-login" id="login-login" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Login" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label for="">Votre mot de passe:</label>
      <input type="password" name="login-password" id="login-password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="password" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button>Entrer</button>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Проблема не в таблице. Отображается таблица и все её элементы правильно, у body, html стоит width: 100vw, height: 100vh. Дело с том, что мне нужно, чтобы, когда я ставил max-height: 0 для элемента, он пропадал, а потом я мог его "развернуть" с max-height больше 0. Но элементу совершенно неважно, стоит max-height/height или нет, он всё равно подстраивается под содержимое

Comment: тогда не max-height может быть а visibility или именно max-height надо ? можете добавить по click некий класс который будет содержать нужное свойство

Comment: Проблема в том, что с visibility и display не работают переходы, а мне надо, чтобы "меню" появлялось плавно. Раньше я уже делал так с max-height/width, но в этот раз элемент почему-то просто отказывается реагировать

Comment: вы бы весь код показали бы и можно было бы думать дальше а то я щас гадаю что надо сделать и не примерно такой а какой у вас есть вместе с css и с описанием проблемы

Comment: Добавил вроде всё

Comment: да не less а обычный css , что бы он воспроизводился как у меня в примере ... вы нажали на кнопку и увидели а не полезли там куда то и начали генерить less

Comment: Извините, в первый раз на сайте, не знал как всё работает. Теперь вроде правильно

Comment: Ещё только сейчас заметил, что у .row margin не работает

Comment: @AlexChashin исправил ответ - смотрите